# Select one from a series of curves in a matplotlib plot and output the choice

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, event-handling

I have read the matplotlib examples on event handling, especially [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html).

What I want to achieve is:
Click the legend of of a line, then set a variable for future output.
To be more specific in that example, click line 1 to: show line 1 only and set xxx=1; Click line 2 to: show line 2 only and set xxx=2

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The example you link to already gives you everything you need. So what have you tried and in how far does it not work?

Comment: What I have tried is to modify the example in such a way: click line 1 and show line 1 only, and set a variable, like x = 1

Comment: That's fine. And what is the problem? Maybe you want to read [ask] and [mcve].